# Can I use codeigniter session_id to SmartScale sessionid in Tungsten Replicator for MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-replication, multi-master-replication

I am trying to use Tungsten Replicator for MySQL.
I am using only one database for whole php application.
and I want to use SmartScale feature. to configure SmartScale it needs a sessionid.
i found some possible sessionid in their doc(DATABASE,USER,CONNECTION,free string).

for PHP based application they suggested to use PHP session_id as SmartScale sessionid where php session_id doesn't change normally in other pages or next requests.
but I am using codeigniter where session_id changes continuously.

in that case can I use codeigniter session_id as SmartScale sessionid to obtain the goal(always get updated data even if read request goes to another slave server where write haven't propagated yet)?

Answer (score 0):

Would a solution be to set an extra kind of session variable that doesn't change unless the session is destroyed?

An example taken from [Session ID is changing in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977259/session-id-is-changing-in-codeigniter):

```
$uniqueId = uniqid($this->CI->input->ip_address(), TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata("my_session_id", md5($uniqueId));
```

Comment: actually i wanted to know that can i use changing session_id as SmartScale sessionid in Tungsten Replicator for MySQL?